# Как добавить символ табуляции в запрос?

Tags: sql, oracle

Довольно детский вопрос, но что-то я с ходу не нагуглил.

Запрос:

```
SELECT '<row>
\t\t<PRMT_ID>'||PRMT_ID||'</PRMT_ID>
</row>' FROM MYTABLE
```

работает, выдавая действительно сочетания символов \t вместо единого символа табуляции.

Как вставить туда символ табуляции? Пока самый стройный вариант такой:

```
SELECT '<row>
'||CHR(9)||CHR(9)||'<PRMT_ID>'||PRMT_ID||'</PRMT_ID>
</row>' FROM MYTABLE
```

Но смотрится что-то не сильно стройно.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще табуляции? XML же их все равно игнорирует

Comment: А человек не игнорирует. Для эстетики, ага.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919394/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81#comment1520872_919394):

> А человек не игнорирует. Для эстетики, ага.

Для эстетики есть функции и алиасы.

Простой пример обоих способов, добавить эстетики в запрос, который можно сразу попробовать и выбрать какой нравится:

```sql
col doc for a40 wrap
with 
function indent (n int, ch char:= chr(9)) return varchar2 is
begin 
    return rpad (ch, n, ch);
end;
function join (arr sys.odciVarchar2List) return varchar2 is
    ret varchar2 (32767);
begin 
    for ix in 1..arr.count loop
        ret := ret||arr(ix); end loop;
    return ret;
end;
mytable (prmt_id) as (
    select 123 from dual
), 
aliases as (
    select chr(9)||chr(9) indent2, chr(10) nl from dual
)
select join (sys.odciVarchar2List ( 
    '<row>', nl,
    indent2,  '<PRMT_ID>', PRMT_ID, '</PRMT_ID>', nl,
    indent(2),'<PRMT_ID>', PRMT_ID, '</PRMT_ID>', nl,
    '</row>'  
)) doc
from mytable cross join aliases 
/

DOC
----------------------------------------
<row>
        <PRMT_ID>123</PRMT_ID>  
        <PRMT_ID>123</PRMT_ID>  
</row>
```